The closed points of the diagonal of the affine line with doubled origin
Here is what I am working on: (The Geometry of Schemes by Eisenbud and Harris)

I have done part a, the locus is $\mathbb{ A}^1_K \setminus \left\{0\right\}$. For part b, my argument is that we get the following diagram and the induced map $\Phi$ by the universal property of the fiber product:

Now using the diagram and definitions,
$$\Phi^{-1}(\Delta)=\left\{ a\in \mathbb{A}^1_K\mid \Phi(a)\in \Delta\right\}=\{a\in \mathbb{A}^1_K | \varphi(\Phi(a))=\psi(\Phi(a)) \}=$$$$\{a\in \mathbb{ A}^1_K | \varphi_1(a)=\varphi_2(a) \}=\mathbb{ A}^1_K \setminus \left\{0\right\}$$
But $\mathbb{ A}^1_K \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ is not closed by part a, hence $\Delta$ cannot be closed.
Is this argument right? I'm not sure about the last part, since $\Phi$ is a morphism of schemes and not just a continuous map. But on the other hand, the morphism contains a continuous map of topological spaces, so the argument should hold.
Another question is, what do I do for the second part of b, when we restrict ourselves to the closed points of $\Delta$, can we say anything about the preimage of it?
